# Garbage collection differences in JS code

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection, return-value

I have this scenario in which some routine is called a lot of times (multiple of millions). While profiling I noticed there is a lot of GC involved, and I managed to isolate a very basic scenario which does not make much sense to me.

There is a huge difference in terms of execution time, pretty much in Scenario2 GC takes like 50% of the total time of my script. My problem is that in the full version of the routine the `this.arr` can have different number of elements each time so I cannot rely on Scenario 1.

To be honest, looking at the code I would have assumed Scenario 1 would yield more GC calls.

Anyone has any idea what could happen?

Thank you!

```
someRoutine(p1, p2) {
  this.arr = [];
  this.arr[0] = p1;
  this.arr[1] = p2;

  // Scenario 1: this is fine, no excessive GC spotted in profiler
  return [this.arr[0], this.arr[1]];
  
  // Scenario 2: this adds a lot of GC calls
  return this.arr;
```

Comment: You will have to share more info. With this code snippet, we do not have enough to try to find a good solution. Why do you call it millions of times? What are p1 and p2. Why exactly is scenario 2 not valid...

Comment: I suppose scenario 1 stores the local variables (the arguments) into a closure, that's why GC doesn't take place. In scenario 2 the variables are garbage collected.

Comment: I think Scenario 1 creates a comparable array with new values. Whereas Scenario 2 passes a direct reference to the original parameters.